# PostgreSQL: Column "crab_id" Specified More than Once

Tags: postgresql, inner-join

With PostgreSQL call,

```
CREATE TABLE condor_xrootd AS
       SELECT * FROM condor INNER JOIN xrootd_ext
       ON (
xrootd_ext.CRAB_Id = condor.CRAB_Id AND
REPLACE(condor.CRAB_ReqName, '_', ':') = xrootd_ext.CRAB_ReqName
);
```

I get the error,

```
$ psql condor -f ./sql/inner_join.sql 
psql:./sql/inner_join.sql:6: ERROR:  column "crab_id" specified more than once
```

Which is understandable because each table has a Crab_Id column. I would like to be able to do my inner join without having to specify the columns because I have around 400 columns in the two tables combined.

Please let me know if I can somehow get rid of this error without listing columns individually.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that speed **and stability** is crucial here as my join might take several days.

Comment: For the join, you can try the USING clause instead of ON when joining on column(s) with the same name, e.g.  condor INNER JOIN xrootd_ext USING(CRAB_Id).  When using this, the resulting join should only have a single instance of the column(s) being joined on.  May or may not work in PostreSQL, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061733/excluding-duplicate-fields-in-a-join
I believe it answers your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table condor_xrootd as
select *
from
    condor
    inner join
    xrootd_ext using (crab_id)
where replace(condor.crab_reqname, '_', ':') = xrootd_ext.crab_reqname
```

Comment: Do you know if your answer will run faster than stas.yaranov's?

Comment: @aidan Probably the same

Answer (score 2):

You create table from a result set which is build of two tables. Your error says that column `crab_id` exists in both `condor` and `xrootd_ext` tables and Postgresql doesn't know which should be selected.

You should specify fields of which you want to create table. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE condor_xrootd AS
       SELECT
          condor.*, -- here we take all fields from condor table
          xrootd_ext.crab_reqName -- here we take crab_reqName field from xrootd_ext
       FROM condor INNER JOIN xrootd_ext
       ON (
xrootd_ext.CRAB_Id = condor.CRAB_Id AND
REPLACE(condor.CRAB_ReqName, '_', ':') = xrootd_ext.CRAB_ReqName
);
```

Comment: Clodoaldo Neto's answer seems to work and is simpler because I want all the XRootD columns. I am concerned by the WHERE clause. Do you know which is faster and/or can you prove it?

Comment: There shouldn't be any performance difference. I think EXPLAIN will prove that. So use what is better for you.