# Optimize a JOIN query, for multiple correspondances between tables

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to optimize a function (MySQL), but the `JOIN` is still not completely understood (I try to make a simple example) :

I have 2 tables :

Table ITEMS

```
ID  |  ID_ORDER | ID_BOX | NAME

001 |  2564     | 123    | SPOON_1
002 |  2564     | 123    | SPOON_2
006 |  2564     | 123    | SHOES_2
007 |  2564     | 123    | SHOES_1
003 |  2565     | 124    | SPOON_1
004 |  2565     | 124    | SPOON_2
008 |  2565     | 124    | SHOES_1
009 |  2565     | 124    | SHOES_2
005 |  2565     | 125    | SPOON_1
010 |  2565     | 125    | SHOES_1
```

The description of objects are linked to the ITEM table by ID_CONTRACT, and NAME.(Not possible to have 2 items with same name inside the same contract).

Table DESCRIPTION :

```
ID_ORDER | NAME_ITEM | LENGTH | WIDTH | ....

2564     | SPOON_1   | 200    | 20 ...
2564     | SPOON_2   | 300    | 20 ...
2564     | SHOES_1   | 500    | 20 ...
2564     | SHOES_2   | 600    | 20 ...
```

Now, I need to know all items I have in the contract, with their description, and I use this query :

```
SELECT *,description.* FROM items INNER JOIN description 
ON (description.ID_CONTRACT=items.ID_CONTRACT AND description.NAME_ITEM=items.NAME) 
WHERE ID_CONTRACT= 2564
```

First, I just read it is not correct query (I need to copy all description fields by hand in query?), because `ID_CONTRACT` is in both tables, and sometimes it gives me mistake(sometimes not), and I read [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061733/excluding-duplicate-fields-in-a-join) that it is not possible to ignore duplicates.
Then I am wondering, as I make a select on ITEMS table, MySQL is looking for each line a correspondance in DESCRIPTION table?
Is there a way to optimize query (another kind of JOIN), so it will not search everytime in ITEMS table, when he meets 2 elements (or more) in ITEMS, with same ID_CONTRACT/NAME ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select *` mean select all the columns from all the tables
and in your case this is like  select items.*,description.* so with the syntax SELECT *,description.*  seems you are trying to select two time the columns for table description

due the fact you have the same column  name `ID_CONTRACT` in both table this produce an ambiguity on coumn name for the DB engine during the join.
for avoid this you simply need  a full reference name in join columns name  eg:

```
table1.col1 = table2.col1
```

this way the db engino know which column form each table must be use for join

```
SELECT items.*, description.* 
FROM items 
INNER JOIN description ON description.ID_CONTRACT=items.ID_CONTRACT 
    AND description.NAME_ITEM=items.NAME
WHERE ID_CONTRACT= 2564
```

for your second part of question

```
 MySQL is looking for each line a correspondance in DESCRIPTION table?
```

yes.

A relation db work on sets of data and retrieve all the correspondance between the tables

if really the rows  are duplicated you could retrive the distinct result using

```
 select DISTICNT col1, col2..
```

tipically a select * from a join on  correctly normalized data set don't produce dulicated  rows (at least you value in one column differ beetween the rows)

but if some column result are not important for you and can be omittedc form the result, this case can produce a result with duplicated  row and you can perform a selective select using only the column name you really need  and apply the disctint clause

Comment: Thanks for explaination. In fact, the duplicate comes not from ID_CONTRACT (understood after reading you), but some fields as "LENGTH", are present in both tables. So I guess I will remove these fields (that are part of desription) from the first table(I know that's not correct, but didn't know about the JOIN when I created them, that's what I'm trying to correct now).

Comment: Then about the `DISTINCT`, I think I didn't explain correctly : My item "SPOON_1" can be placed in several boxes (sometimes it can be hundred times), so for each element SPOON_1 found, it will look for its description? Or will SQL see that in my list of items, I have 100 items with same ID_CONTRACT and NAME, so will look for description only once, and then apply it to each SPOON_1?

Comment: for this detail you should post a specific question with a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text  ..  (i'm not in your db and a sample help me a lot.) once done comment me the link to the new question ..

Comment: ok thanks, here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402148/optimize-a-join-query-which-join-would-be-the-best