# Optimize a JOIN query, which "JOIN" would be the best?

Tags: c#, sql, join, mariadb

I have 2 tables :

Table ITEMS

| ID | ID_ORDER | ID_BOX | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2564 | 123 | SPOON_1 |
| 002 | 2564 | 123 | SPOON_2 |
| 006 | 2564 | 123 | SHOES_2 |
| 007 | 2564 | 123 | SHOES_1 |
| 003 | 2565 | 124 | SPOON_1 |
| 004 | 2565 | 124 | SPOON_2 |
| 008 | 2565 | 124 | SHOES_1 |
| 009 | 2565 | 124 | SHOES_2 |
| 005 | 2565 | 125 | SPOON_1 |
| 010 | 2565 | 125 | SHOES_1 |

Table DESCRIPTION :

| ID_ORDER | NAME | LENGTH | WIDTH | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2564 | SPOON_1 | 200 | 20 ... |  |
| 2564 | SPOON_2 | 300 | 20 ... |  |
| 2564 | SHOES_1 | 500 | 20 ... |  |
| 2564 | SHOES_2 | 600 | 20 ... |  |

The description of objects are linked to the ITEM table by ID_ORDER, and NAME.(Not possible to have 2 items with same name, and different description inside the same order).

The way I found faster is using C# (I compared all times) :

1. I make a request `SELECT * FROM items WHERE ID_ORDER=2567`, that returns me a `List<Item>`.
2. Then I group by name, to have the list of items'names in the list :

   List listNames=listItems.Select(x=>"'"+x.Name+"'").Distinct().ToList();
3. I make a second request that will look for all descriptions corresponding :

   string query = "SELECT * FROM description WHERE ID_ORDER=2567 AND NAME IN ("+string.Join(",",listNames)+")";

Even if I have 1000 items in my order, but only 50 different items, in 1st query I return all 1000 items, then on 2nd query I return only 50 descriptions.

So on the end I just need to do something like :

```
foreach(Item item in listItems)
{
    item.Description=listDescriptions.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name==item.Name);
}
```

Now, I am trying to do all in a single SQL request. Here is what I have now :

```
SELECT * FROM items INNER JOIN description 
ON (description.ID_ORDER=items.ID_ORDER AND description.NAME=items.NAME) 
WHERE ID_ORDER= 2564
```

The problem, as I understand, is SQL will search the list of items, then will search a description for each of them, and it looks more time, because the description is big data.
Is there a faster way that would make SQL first read all descriptions corresponding to my list of items, then apply description to each of them? I also tried RIGHT JOIN (I believed it would act like that), but it take almost as much time as simple JOIN, using C# is still the faster way.

Comment: @Zaki thanks for edit, but how did you do such tables? could be useful in future

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: "What behaviour does SQL have?" is unclear. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS [mre]

Comment: @philipxy tried to explain better, it it is still unclear I just don't know what to do... I would just delete the question, but as some people already helped and all, I believed it wouldn't be fair for them.

Comment: You still don't distinguish between the defined result vs implementation. PS Always try to edit a post but not in a way to invalidate reasonable answers. Note you already have an answer like the duplicate I linked. One can't delete one's own post if it has an upvoted or accepted answer. PS The question re EXPLAIN (as clearly can be expected) is also a duplicate. Please research (including reading the manual & googling with 'site:stackoverflow.com') before considering posting a question. PS Please don't add "EDIT"s, edit to the best presentation possible at edit time.

Comment: See my edited comment. PS If you don't clearly phrase your actual question precisely & clearly, you can't expect to (re)search reasonably.

Comment: @philipxy as I said, I think I didn't use the proper terms, that's why I gave a simple example.  What I was looking for, is a way to use a join, having the same behaviour as in my edit. (in original question, I was explaining it is acting as in  behaviour 1), and I want it to act as in 2(I believed there would be such possibility, but the documentations I read don't talk about that case)) ). If even now, the question is not clear enough, then excuse me but I don't know how to explain better. (P.S. : I don't blame you, if none could understand the question, I only can blame myself)

Comment: "Please clarify via edits, not comments." "Ask 1 clear specific researched non-duplicate question." [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the EXPLAIN command, that will let you know how MySQL is planning to answer your query. You can use it to optimise your query to run faster, or just to understand how it works. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html

For example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM items INNER JOIN description 
ON (description.ID_ORDER=items.ID_ORDER AND description.NAME=items.NAME) 
WHERE ID_ORDER=2564
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` includes the rows both tables *that match based on the `ON`*.  (Or the relationship may be hiding in the `WHERE`, where they don't belong.  `WHERE` should be used only for filtering.)

`LEFT JOIN` includes all the rows of the "left" table and any matching rows of the "right" table, whether or not they match.  Non-matching rows show `NULL` in the columns.

`FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON ... WHERE b.id IS NULL` is the pattern for finding rows of `a` for which the corresponding `b` row is *missing*`.

`RIGHT JOIN` is a `LEFT JOIN` with the tables swapped.  (Don't use this; it makes my brain hurt.)

`CROSS JOIN` has all combinations of the rows of both tables.  It is equivalent to having no `ON` and no 'relationship' in the `WHERE` clause.

"commajoin" is old syntax:  `FROM a,b WHERE a.foo=b.foo`.  Don't use it; responders on this forum will slap your hand if you do.

The keywords `INNER` and `OUTER` are irrelevant and ignored *by MySQL*.

`FULL OUTER JOIN` is a feature and syntax that MySQL does not support.  It can be simulated with a `JOIN` and a `LEFT JOIN` combined by a `UNION`.